# how to display a picture on laravel?

Tags: html, laravel, image, laravel-blade

i'm trying to display picture on laravel.

I did that : `<img src="public/medoc.jpg" alt="Toxic Project">`.

To be sure at 100% it is not a link problem i writed `public/medoc.jpg` on terminal and it's launch the picture.

I try to diplay it on the welcome view.

I have alredy tried with : `"{{ asset('public/medoc.jpg') }}"`

What's wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asset() helper provided by Laravel is already referencing to the public folder.
So all you need to do is :

```
<img src="{{asset('medoc.jpg')}}">
```

And Laravel will do the rest for you.

Answer (score 3):

> if you use asset that means you are already in public folder so no need to write public..try this one..

```
"{{asset('medoc.jpg)}}"
```